# Win cool site swag with our birthday party!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, contest

## HAPPY BIRTHDAY RPG!

To celebrate this momentous occasion, your moderator team and I have put together a fun contest!

### Rules

This contest will run from **29 April 2013 to 31 May 2013**.

At the end of the month, we will give 5 total prizes to users based on a raffle. Users gain "raffle tickets" by collecting points; each point acts as a ticket into the pool.

- 1 point for each Announcer badge gained during the month, (don't forget to use the url from "share" to qualify for this)
- 3 points for each Booster badge gained during the month.
- 5 points for each Publicist badge gained during the month.
- 2 points for each Nice Answer or Nice Question earned in the following tags:

  [13th-age](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/13th-age) [7th-sea](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7th-sea) [a-game-of-thrones](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-game-of-thrones) [adnd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adnd) [adnd-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adnd-2e) [adventurer-conqueror-king](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventurer-conqueror-king) [all-flesh-must-be-eaten](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/all-flesh-must-be-eaten) [anima-beyond-fantasy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anima-beyond-fantasy) [apocalypse-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse-world) [ars-magica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ars-magica) [ars-magica-5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ars-magica-5) [basic-role-playing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic-role-playing) [battlestar-galactica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica) [battletech](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battletech) [black-crusade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-crusade) [buck-rogers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buck-rogers) [burning-wheel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burning-wheel) [cadillacs-and-dinosaurs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cadillacs-and-dinosaurs) [call-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu) [call-of-cthulhu-d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu-d20) [changeling-dreaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changeling-dreaming) [changeling-lost](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changeling-lost) [coda](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coda) [continuum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuum) [cortex](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortex) [cortex-plus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortex-plus) [cyberpunk-2020](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk-2020) [d20-modern](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20-modern) [d6-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d6-system) [dangerous-journeys](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dangerous-journeys) [dark-ages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-ages) [dark-heresy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-heresy) [deadlands](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadlands) [deathwatch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathwatch) [delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green) [diaspora](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diaspora) [dictionary-of-mu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary-of-mu) [dnd-becmi](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-becmi) [dnd-bx](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-bx) [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) [dogs-in-the-vineyard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs-in-the-vineyard) [dread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dread) [dresden-files](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files) [dungeon-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-world) [earthdawn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthdawn) [eclipse-phase](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-phase) [en-garde](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/en-garde) [exalted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted) [fallout-pnp-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-pnp-rpg) [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) [fear-itself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fear-itself) [feng-shui](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feng-shui) [fiasco](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiasco) [freemarket](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freemarket) [fudge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fudge) [gamma-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-world) [geist-sin-eaters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geist-sin-eaters) [genius-transgression](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genius-transgression) [golarion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golarion) [gumshoe](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gumshoe) [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) [heavygear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heavygear) [heresy-engine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heresy-engine) [hero-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hero-system) [heroquest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroquest) [hollow-earth-expedition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollow-earth-expedition) [hunter-vigil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunter-vigil) [in-a-wicked-age](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-a-wicked-age) [in-nomine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-nomine) [interface-zero](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-zero) [jade-regent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jade-regent) [kult](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kult) [l5r](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r) [l5r-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r-4e) [labyrinth-lord](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labyrinth-lord) [lady-blackbird](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lady-blackbird) [laundry](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laundry) [legend](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend) [legends-of-anglerre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends-of-anglerre) [leverage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leverage) [little-fears](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-fears) [lotfp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotfp) [mage-ascension](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-ascension) [mage-awakening](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-awakening) [maid](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maid) [marvel-heroic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-heroic) [mazes-and-minotaurs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes-and-minotaurs) [mechwarrior-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechwarrior-4e) [microscope](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microscope) [mini-six](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-six) [mouse-guard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse-guard) [mutant-city-blues](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutant-city-blues) [mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds) [natural-weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-weapon) [nobilis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nobilis) [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod) [odnd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odnd) [over-the-edge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/over-the-edge) [palladium-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palladium-system) [paranoia](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paranoia) [reign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reign) [rogue-trader](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-trader) [rolemaster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster) [runequest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runequest) [savage-worlds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savage-worlds) [savage-worlds-fantasy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savage-worlds-fantasy) [serenity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serenity) [shadowrun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun) [shadowrun-sr4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-sr4) [shock](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shock) [sifrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sifrp) [spirit-of-the-century](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit-of-the-century) [spycraft](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spycraft) [star-trek](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) [star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) [star-wars-d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-d20) [star-wars-saga-edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-saga-edition) [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system) [storytelling-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storytelling-system) [sword-noir](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-noir) [tekumel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tekumel) [tftfv](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tftfv) [the-dark-eye](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-eye) [the-esoterrorists](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-esoterrorists) [the-multiverse-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-multiverse-rpg) [the-one-ring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring) [the-riddle-of-steel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-riddle-of-steel) [tolkien](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) [torg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torg) [toward-one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toward-one) [trail-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trail-of-cthulhu) [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) [tremulus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tremulus) [tsoy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsoy) [ubiquity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubiquity) [unisystem](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unisystem) [universalis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universalis) [vampire-masquerade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-masquerade) [vampire-requiem](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-requiem) [warp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warp) [werewolf-forsaken](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf-forsaken) [wfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp) [wfrp-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-1e) [wfrp-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-2e) [wfrp-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-3e) [wh40k](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wh40k) [wild-talents](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wild-talents) [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) [wraith-oblivion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wraith-oblivion) [wraith-orpheus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wraith-orpheus)

**Drawings will be held on 1 June** but I'll update this post / answers with a running leaderboard each week on Monday.

Sharing badges can be earned for ANY question/answer, regardless of when that post was made or what tag it is in.

The "Nice Question" and "Nice Answer" badges MUST **both**: be earned during the contest period AND the associated post be created in the contest period. Badges earned for posts made prior to the contest starting are not eligible.

**Other:**

- If your question is closed, it is disqualified.
- If your answer is deleted, it is disqualified.
- If you are found to be using sockpuppets or caught gaming the system, you will be disqualified.
- If you are suspended during the contest period, you are disqualified.
- We reserve the right to alter or append to these rules as circumstances arise during the event.

### Prizes

**Three users** will receive site swag items (t-shirts, stickers, etc), and **two users** will receive RPG books or PDFs based on their most active tags.

Comment: It would be nice if our bloggers and social media types would share this around.

Comment: What timezone are we using to calculate April 29th and May 31st? UTC or something else? (In other words, has the contest started yet or do I need to wait a few more hours?)

Comment: @Thunderforge UTC, as everything on Stack is timed that way. :)

Comment: Is the [[tag:untagged]] tag supposed to be in the list?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think that might have been an auto-deleted tag? I'll double-check this afternoon. :)

Comment: And by sock puppets you mean fake accounts (and not the "character sheet" of Argyle & Crew), right?
Also, we need a "kids" tag.

Comment: I just wrote a query to track progress: http://data.stackexchange.com/role-playing%20games/query/113676/first-anniversary-contest

Comment: Why does [dnd-4e] not qualify?

Comment: @Soulrift I believe the goal is to get some more system diversity. So no 4e, 3.x, or Pathfinder (which are all 5+ times more common than the next lower system).

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton The query doesn't seem to get the Nice Question/Nice Answer badges from qualifying tags.  Either that or I'm looking at the wrong things (it seems like there should be a lot more names in the results in any case).

Comment: @lunin See above:The "Nice Question" and "Nice Answer" badges MUST both: be earned during the contest period AND the associated post be created in the contest period. Badges earned for posts made prior to the contest starting are not eligible.

Comment: I just now noticed that the contest was system-specific. Curse you, [tag:gm-techniques]!

Comment: What's the status of the drawing?

Answer (score 10):

When sharing a question, make sure to use the share URL provided by the share link, it has an extra bit:

> https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2897/760

That second number is your userid, which means you get credit for sharing the link when someone clicks on it.

Comment: Ooo excellent point that might need to be added into the post itself!

Comment: I didn't see a good place for it, and answers here would make an excellent place for tips and collective wisdom.

Comment: Fair enough! A+++

Answer (score 8):

Alright! Our anniversary contest has come to a close! It took a bit longer than the start of June to announce this, but that's because in a special twist, we decided to do a [live drawing in our chat system](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/rpg-2013-anniversary-contest-drawing)! It was a bit of a short-notice thing, so sorry to those who could not attend. Linked earlier is a transcript of the event and how our drawing was made.

The winners of our site swag are: [Extrakun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1981/extrakun), [Thunderforge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/7373/thunderforge), and [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw)!

The winners of sourcebooks or PDFs are: [Erik Schmidt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1871/erik-schmidt) and [Dakeyras](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/5746/dakeyras)!

Over the upcoming days, the moderators and I will be contacting the winners to arrange for shipping and prize selection.

Thanks again to *everyone* who participated in this contest and made it a smashing success! ♪

Comment: Sweet! Congratulations to the other winners, and thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Today my copy of *Godlike* arrived in the mail. Thank you very much for the the contest reward.

Now if you'll excuse me, I have an awful lot of reading to do.