# Who has a chance to win free stuff? (Updated 26-May)

Tags: discussion

A place to post reports on competition for our [first anniversary contest](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/win-cool-site-swag-with-our-birthday-party).

Using the query found: http://data.stackexchange.com/role-playing%20games/query/114968/breakdown-of-tickets-for-first-contest

Answer (score 4):

19 May

```
   User          tickets reason                                                                                  
------------- ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Erik Schmidt  2       Answer: What RPG systems are Designed for a "Traditional" Call of Cthulhu Scenario      
Erik Schmidt  1       Announcer Badge                                                                         
Magician      2       Question: Wealth in tremulus: insane or horrific?                                       
okeefe        2       Answer: What Works Inspired Paranoia?                                                   
pconcepcion   2       Question: Why the bad guys don't just teleport somewhere drop a bomb and teleport back? 
SevenSidedDie 2       Answer: Why the bad guys don't just teleport somewhere drop a bomb and teleport back?   
Thunderforge  2       Question: What Works Inspired Paranoia?                                                 
wax eagle     2       Answer: Why the bad guys don't just teleport somewhere drop a bomb and teleport back?
```

Answer (score 3):

## 26-May

```
User          tickets reason                                                                                  
------------- ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
BESW          2       Answer: Do you have to reveal your NPC's aspects?                                       
BESW          2       Answer: What/how many different cities are officially supported by Dresden Files?       
Dakeyras      2       Question: What/how many different cities are officially supported by Dresden Files?     
Dan Rasmussen 2       Answer: How can I let players make more choices during combat?                          
Erik Schmidt  2       Answer: Players who want a dayjob for a megacorp. Should I allow it?                    
Erik Schmidt  2       Answer: What RPG systems are Designed for a "Traditional" Call of Cthulhu Scenario      
Erik Schmidt  1       Announcer Badge                                                                         
Lunin         2       Answer: In a high magic setting, how should I introduce "unnatural" magic?              
Magician      2       Question: Technological warfare: how does Iron Man fight?                               
Magician      2       Question: Wealth in tremulus: insane or horrific?                                       
okeefe        2       Answer: Encouraging players to not cheat the item purchase system?                      
okeefe        2       Answer: What Works Inspired Paranoia?                                                   
pconcepcion   2       Question: Why the bad guys don't just teleport somewhere drop a bomb and teleport back? 
SevenSidedDie 2       Answer: Why the bad guys don't just teleport somewhere drop a bomb and teleport back?   
Thunderforge  2       Question: What Works Inspired Paranoia?                                                 
wax eagle     2       Answer: Technological warfare: how does Iron Man fight?                                 
wax eagle     2       Answer: Why the bad guys don't just teleport somewhere drop a bomb and teleport back?
```

Answer (score 1):

### 13 May

Three people have passed the nice question/answer threshold:

```
Question Title                                                             User         Type     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------ -------- 
What RPG systems are Designed for a "Traditional" Call of Cthulhu Scenario Erik Schmidt Answer   
What Works Inspired Paranoia?                                              okeefe       Answer   
What Works Inspired Paranoia?                                              Thunderforge Question
```

No one has any of the publicity badges yet!

Comment: This is also a good time to tell me if my queries are wrong.

Comment: I forgot this was even ongoing. rpg.se doesn't seem like a publicity-heavy site.

Comment: It's not. But we'd like to get some more publicity? :)

Comment: Will the staff give us a modified site banner or anything that will make people remember there's a competition going on still?

Comment: (By which I mean anything really that will remind them on every visit, so they don't forget. I doubt many forgot the Christmas event was going on once they started finding out - there were a lot of things to remind someone about it)

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton is there a resource for explaining how the publicity feature works?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's an excellent meta question.